# Awesome font + App engine not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, fonts, configuration, font-awesome

Actualy i'm trying to use awesome-font into appengine, badly this is not working for me.
i think that this font is not loaded at all.

you can actualy check the rendring here : 
[www.tazimehdi.com](http://tazimehdi.com) [the bar just bellow "Find me on ..." topic tag ].

i actualy tried lot of solutions on internet but in vain.

here is my current configuration :

### appengine-web.xml

```
<static-files>
    <include path="**" >
        <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </include>
      <include path="fonts/**"  />
      <include path="WEB-INF/fonts/**"/>
</static-files>
```

### web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the developer tools in chrome... the font files return 404 - NOT FOUND

[image]

Comment: yes exacly this is the problem.... but how to resolve it using appengine. cause when i just start the index.html file, everything works fine ,and once i started in appengine he can no more find the the font.

thanks for your answer ^^